# How to get title of a website in UTF-8 format?

Tags: c#, .net, encoding, utf-8, html-agility-pack

I want to get title of a website. I'm using **client.Encoding**, It's almost perfect but there's something wrong.

It returns me *"Budapeşte&#039de gezilecek yerler | Skyscanner Haberler"* but the title has apostrophe instead of unicode.

The Turkish character "ş" is OK.

```
string baslikCek()
        {
            Uri url = new Uri("https://www.skyscanner.com.tr/haberler/budapestede-gezilecek-yerler");
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            string html = client.DownloadString(url);
            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
            doc.LoadHtml(html);
            String title = (from x in doc.DocumentNode.Descendants()
                            where x.Name.ToLower() == "title"
                            select x.InnerText).FirstOrDefault().ToString();
            return title;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example shown here is incorrect, `&#039` is missing the trailing `;`.

But it is correct from the server, so you may do this:

```
return System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(title);
```

This is not the same as `Encoding.UTF8`, which is the binary encoding of the string data.